# Publishing a book with a big publisher

Tags: journals, books

This question is not strictly mathematical (as there are not concrete mathematics on it), but I guess that could be of interest to the community.

I am considering to write a research graduate book on some advanced material in my area of research and I am considering to knock the door to a big publisher to see if they would be interested on publishing it.

My question is the following: if interested, which is the usual offer the publisher would propose? I do not know if they pay once (or null), and which is the topic of the royalties (if they apply at some moment of the life of the book).

I have some experience with some non-technical dissemination books not fitting inside one big company (Springer, Cambridge Univ. Press, AMS, etc), and I guess their conditions are way different to a technical book on mathematics.

Comment: To me, "a big editorial" is part of a book or a newspaper, not someone who publishes a book, so I have trouble parsing this.  What does "a big editorial" mean to you?  (Maybe it's obvious and I'm just being dense.)

Comment: for me big editorial in the context of mathematics. This means an editorial that 1) publish mathematical specialized books and 2) it published worldwide and 3) publishes in English at least

Comment: I think https://academia.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit for this question.

Comment: I agree with @SamHopkins's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421662/publishing-a-book-with-a-big-editorial#comment1083428_421662), but, also, I [still](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421662/publishing-a-book-with-a-big-editorial#comment1083427_421662) don't know what "an editorial" (big or otherwise) means to you (and, in case others are confused, it may help to clarify this, wherever your question winds up).  Are you using it to mean a publishing house?

Comment: editorial --> publisher; royalties are typically a percentage of the book price, and vary widely (5% would be on the low end, 20% on the high end); a freshman calculus book that is widely adopted could provide serious income, a specialized text is likely to provide little or no financial benefits.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, while I agree [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421662/publishing-a-book-with-a-big-publisher#comment1083442_421662) seems to be the only meaning that makes sense, I think such [changes](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/421662/2) are best left to the original asker.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have one contract that offers $10$%, rising to $15$% "if receipts exceed £40,000"! :-)

Comment: I had a recent contract for "10% of the net profit" (which came down to I think appx \$4 per copy for a book priced appx \$80). There was also a one-time payment (of a few hundred dollars) for "e-books sold part of a package". I doubt there will be any more payment for electronic copies beyond that.